# Is there a need to title every section of a homepage?

Tags: e-commerce, homepage

I have a typical homepage for ecommerce with a section that shows product categories, a section with a few magazine logos to show where they are featured, etc

My question is, is there a need to title each of these sections? With 'products' and 'as featured on' labels?

What are the pros and cons? I am trying to leep the page as slim as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is: **Don't make the user guess**

Each section of the website should be clearly distinguishable. With the evolution minimalistic design patterns, dividing pages with lines and boxes are being avoided. This makes **labeling** even more of a priority! Take a look at this very page for reference; the question, the answers and the side sections are clearly labelled.

Despite standards and general trends, each website/application is different from one another. Even though some sections remain common, the user shouldn't have to make an assumption about them.

> To help people navigate around the page, they need to be able to identify distinctive page sections such as navigation, main content, headers, and footers.

Source: [W3 WAI](https://www.w3.org/WAI)

Answer (score 1):

**Not always but it is recommended you do.**

You can have a visual of featured products but without (title) text it might not be clear what it is and what you want your customers to do. Use a title to label your visuals.

If you do not use a title, be sure to have at least a clear call-to-action for your users to guide them.

You can put titles over your visuals to save space. If you do so, make sure your text remains readable.

> If you place text over a background image, make sure it’s readable by
>   providing adequate contrast. Subtle tweaks can increase the contrast
>   without affecting the overall aesthetic of the site.

More on that here: [Ensure High Contrast for Text Over Images](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/text-over-images/)